# $f_m:=x^m+x^{-m^2},m\in\mathbb{Z}$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$ basis for $\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis

I want to show that $x$ cannot be expressed as a sum  $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}q_kf_k,q_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: $x=f_1-(1/2)f_{-1}$. What is the real question? The one in the title?

Comment: yes it is the one in the title. I wanted to answer the question by showing $(f_m)$ cannot be a basis because $x$ cannot be expressed as a $\mathbb{Q}$ combination. But maybe you have an other idea

Comment: My guess is that $x^2$ might not be in the span. But I need a nap first :-/